# Incorrect error near ","

Tags: asp.net

I used following query to in C# and got error incorrect syntax near ", "

```
" insert into 
         TEMP (Temp,Temp_price,CS_id) 
  Select 
         Menu_item, Menu_Price 
  where 
        Menu_id=@Menu_id , Select top 1 User_ID from UserInformation ";
```

while `@menu_id =button.command` arguments

Comment: Why you are passing two quries ??what your are trying to achieve

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to do? and the tables structures. Your insert statement is not correct.

Comment: Your insert into has three column and values containing 2 column.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have 2 SELECT statements in that query  you can try  something like this

`insert into #temp(slno,name)
select table1.slno,table2.name from table1,table2
where table1.slno=table2.slno`